# 'Bad credentials' in /home/webadmin/indiashipping/vendor/symfony/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:72

Tags: symfony

i am not able to use fosuserbundle for login and register when i click on login button the page show following attahed error![enter image description here][1]

my security.yml file is

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

config.yml file is

imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:       ~      # { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

## Twig Configuration

twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

## Assetic Configuration

assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        ['indiaShippingMainBundle']
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

```
    yui_css:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar
    yui_js:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar
```

## Doctrine Configuration

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

```
form:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
```

## Swiftmailer Configuration

swiftmailer:
    transport:  smtp
    host:       email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    username:   AKIAJZVRWLH6IRYTZS4Q
    password:   AgKqNzB0xN3kWiwIJRKKnioRceUERKdUdSQ1ot9u/vp0
    encryption: tls
    port:       587

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: indiaShipping\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: indaiShi_user_registration
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
            from_email:

## address:        lasri.mehdi@gmail.com

```
            address:        support@indiashipping.net
            sender_name:    Support - India Shipping
```

Answer (score 0):

In your security.yml file, first you have an indentation problem :

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
```

...should be :

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
```

Then your encoder is not configured :

```
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

I suggest you to check your configuration with [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).